# Autocomplete Jquery UI not listing

Tags: php, mysql, html, jquery-ui-autocomplete

Auto-complete which I tested in localhost its working fine. the same source code I implemented into our site. Am getting json response from the server but search page results are not listing. I thought it would be js overlapping. I tried with conflict method as well. its not displaying the results.

please suggest me the correct method so that I can overcome this issue. I attached my source code here for your referral.

auto.php

```
 $term=$_GET["term"];
    $result = mysqli_query($dbCon,"SELECT * FROM PRODUCT where COMMENT like '%$term%'  order by COMMENT limit 20");
   $json=array();
    while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
           $json[]=array('value'=> $row["COMMENT"]);

    }
    echo json_encode($json);
```

index.php

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
                        $(document).ready(function(){
                            $("#searchText").autocomplete({
                                source:'<?php echo SCRIPT_ROOT?>auto.php',
                                minLength:1
                            });
                        });
                </script>
             <form>
<div class="col-xs-11 col-sm-11 col-md-11 col-lg-11" style="padding:0px;">
<input type="text" name="searchText" id="searchText"></div></form>
```

[Reference Link](http://vcompare4u.com/kaon/auto.php?term=laptops)